# Can browser called from RSelenium run in the backround

Tags: r, rselenium

I am working on a windows 7 machine. Is it possible to run remoteDriver()$open() from the RSelenium library and have the browser run in the background (i.e not visible).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. The default browser for `RSelenium` is Firefox. However, `RSelenium` even supports headless browsing using `PhantomJS` which is described in the [respective vignette](http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-headless) in detail.

In general, for leveraging `PhanomJS` under Windows 7 you just need to

- [download PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) and add the folder path to the `phantomjs.exe` as an additional entry to the user or system PATH variable in the `Environment Variable` menu on your system (e.g. `C:\Program Files\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows`) *Note: `phantomjs.exe` itself is not part of the path specification.*
- **replace the code snippets** at the beginning and at the end of your code like described next

**Default browsing:**

```
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDrv <- remoteDriver()
remDrv$open()

...

remDrv$quit()
remDrv$closeServer()
```

**Headless browsing:**

```
pJS <- phantom()
remDrv <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'phantomjs')
remDrv$open()

...

remDrv$close()
pJS$stop()
```

#### Additional advice

**Command line arguments and POODLE**

Pay attention to the [command line arguments](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) which you can pass to `phantom`.

For instance, PhantomJS uses SSLv3 by default which is discouraged by every server since POODLE.

The workaround is to call `phantom` with `--ssl-protocol=tlsv1`:

```
pJS <- phantom(extras = c('--ssl-protocol=tlsv1'))
```

**Timing issues**

One thing that often happens with PhantomJS is timing issues. Code that works with browsers such as Firefox and Chrome breaks with PhantomJS because PhantomJS is too fast.

You can solve this issue by placing `Sys.sleep` calls between the different `remoteDriver` calls.

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems i am getting stuck at the very beginning.

i get the following error:
> remDrv$open()
`[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
   Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
   class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`      
when i run
  
        
`checkForServer();
startServer();
pJS <- phantom("C:\\Users\\phantomjs.exe", extras = c('--ssl-protocol=tlsv1'));
remDrv <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'phantomjs');
remDrv$open()`

Comment: I still get the same error. This is what i run:  
pJS <- phantom("C:\\Users\\phantomjs.exe", extras = c('--ssl-protocol=tlsv1')); remDrv <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'phantomjs'); remDrv$open()

Comment: I think this is what i am not getting (sorry for busting ..)
**place the folder in which the phantomjs.exe resides in the user or system PATH variable (e.g., C:\Program Files\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows)**
i am placing it in  the path i get from the `getwd()` in r

Comment: done this, i get `Error in phantom() : PhantomJS binary not located`.    
only when i unzip phantom in the getwd() path or when i run `phantom("pathWherephEXEis\\phantomjs.exe")` i do not get the above error. In those cases though i go back to error described in my first comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in the chat area](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70007/discussion-between-alex23lemm-and-dimitris-ps).